# Remove part of filename based prefix

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I have a file named:

'SomePrefix_?????.jpg'

I am trying to remove part of filename after 'SomePrefix_' String.

I know the prefix part but don't know the rest.
how can I remove any character after 'SomePrefix_' from filename?

I also try this to find filename:

```
$files = preg_grep('~^SomePrefix_' , scandir("/home/mydomain/public_html/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/"));
```

but returns nothing.

how can I remove end part of filename based prefix?

---

Update

Expected Output:

assume I have 'SomePrefix_ copy(3)326  s.jpg' in server.

I want to find this file and rename it to 'SomePrefix_.jpg'

Comment: Do you want to rename a filename if it is contains your defined prefix?

Comment: Try `$files = preg_replace('~^(SomePrefix_).*(?=\.|$)' , '$1', scandir("/home/mydomain/public_html/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/"));`

Comment: Could you please provide some (at least 1) examples with expected output?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I've updated my question and wrote my expected output.

Comment: Well, try `preg_filter('~^(SomePrefix_).*(\.jpe?g)$~', '$1$2', $files)`. It will only return the changed file names where the match occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`preg_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-filter.php) solution:

```
$result = preg_filter('~^(SomePrefix_).*(\.jpe?g)$~', '$1$2', $files);
```

It will only return the changed file names where the match occurred.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/myX5e3/1).

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of strings
- `(SomePrefix_)` - Group 1 capturing the prefix as literal text
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `(\.jpe?g)` - Group 2: `.jpeg` or `.jpg`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: is there anyway to find the real name of the file?

Comment: What do you mean? If you just need to get the files that match the pattern, use `preg_grep`. You are already using it.